# Base64.getEncoder().encode and generate PDF in C#

Tags: c#, base64

I am working on a project that uses a web service developed in Java. The response of this web service is a json file with a key generated with this java method (`Base64.getEncoder().encode(array)`, where "array" is `byte[]`. This key is supposedly a binary to generate the pdf, but as much as I try, the pdf is not generated correctly, it cannot be opened.

Can anybody help me to generate a **pdf** with this response in **C#**?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert from Base64, to byte and then get the pdf:

Check this example:

```
string base64EncodedFile = // Get the string representation from the api

using (System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Create("c:\\saved.pdf))
{
    System.Byte[] byteArray = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedFile);
    stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}
```

For more information check [wikipedia on base 64](http://In%20computer%20science,%20Base64%20is%20a%20group%20of%20binary-to-text%20encoding%20schemes%20that%20represent%20binary%20data%20in%20an%20ASCII%20string%20format%20by%20translating%20it%20into%20a%20radix-64%20representation.)

> Base64 is a way to encode binary data into an ASCII character set
>   known to pretty much every computer system, in order to transmit the
>   data without loss or modification of the contents itself

And that is why the java service does the conversion.